# How can I maintain and update a subtree in Git with local changes?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I've been mucking about with git-subtree and read-tree for a few hours now and I just can't seem to make this work how I have envisioned. Maybe my methodology is flawed, but here is the basic idea:

- There is a parent repository, `A`, which shall contain another pre-existing repo/module/project/tree `B`, residing within the subdirectory `b/`.
- The contents of `b/` are initially retrieved using a tag (version) reference from `B`'s remote (GitHub), and committed/merged into `A`.
- During the course of development, local modifications need to be made to files within `b/` and committed to `A`.
- Periodically, new tags (versions) need to be fetched from `B`'s remote and merged into `A` with an appropriate merge strategy (although I expect manual resolution will be necessary in some cases).

How can I go about this?

Comment: Well, the standard scenario allows one to perform updates from the upstream (`B` in your terminology). Have you read [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) and what steps cause problems?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that document on my own, and the official git documentation only describes the low-level subtree merge strategy which I found somewhat confusing. I'm all sorted now, git-subtree add and pull seem to work great for my needs.